Shrink and Auto-Resize Bookworm
EDIT:   My problem was caused by a software mismatch on my work machine.  The pishrink.sh program works perfectly on Bookworm.  https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink
I've been using pishrink.sh to shrink a disk image of the Raspberry Pi OS to avoid problems with copying it onto SD cards that might not be exactly the same size as my image, and to make a compressed file for distribution.
I made them auto-resize by adding init=resize.sh to cmdline.txt and creating the necessary files.
This doesn't work with Bookworm.  Using my old approach the resize code complains that boot and root are on different devices.  I conjecture this is because boot is on a ramdisk at that point in the process.
I've tried saving the original cmdline.txt and restoring it just before making my image.  That dumps me into BusyBox.
So, using the Bookworm release, how can I make an image that's shrunken and which automagically resizes itself on the first boot?
And the answer is to use pishrink: https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink

Clarify what pishrink.sh does and where you got it (and how old it is). Shrink & image is a poor backup strategy, there are better options which don't copy all the unnecessary parts of an image.

Good question, I have been using a 32G card to install a new image, boot it up and then coping the boot and root filesystem to a different card with the size that I have formatted to the size that I would like to have with rsync.

@bstipe You don't say how you are "coping(sic) the boot and root filesystem to a different card" but this is likely to result in an unbootable image due to mismatching PARTUUID.

@Milliways pishrink came from here: https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink  I've had trouble with the option to set for resize, and so have, pre-Bookworm, used my own approach.  My copy is about a year old.  I don't see any remarks that it's been updated for Bookworm.

@Milliways  I'm not doing this for backup; I"m making distribution SD cards to give to K-12 teachers.  These people are beginners, so I need "insert and go" images.

Why not use the SD Copier included in Raspberry Pi OS. I use other methods to create backups but use SD Copier when I want to make a copy. It is fast, reliable and works to any size SD Card which it formats. I usually use the option to create new PARTUUID so the cards are "unique" i.e. can be mounted on a Pi without conflict. I think copies should have a unique hostname but that is your choice

I looked at the script which is hardly well documented. I guess it fails to check the size of boot partition (at least I couldn't find anything that looks like this). Bookworm has a 512M boot partition rather than 256M.

@Milliways  Thank you for looking at pishrink.sh.  If I can make a suitably-shrunken disk image, I can mass-duplicate SD cards, ten at a time, with the equipment I have.  I can only make one at a time with the SD copier.

If you can make one card the size you want you can that copy to get an image; there's not much point in making it truly minimal  (eg. 2.5 GB) if all of the cards it is going to be put on are at least 4 GB.  That said, it is not very hard to create a fat formatted device image with two partitions of whatever size,  format them appropriately, then just copy the content over.

@goldilocks The problem I'm trying to solve is that not all e.g. 16 GiB cards are exactly the same size.  If I build on one that is "a bit big," I can't copy to one that's a bit smaller.

My point was if you can use SD copier to create one 4 GiB you can copy that to an image and then write it to any 8+ GiB card.  You could also shrink the second partition on the card before you copy it to an image.

@goldilocks  My shrunken image is 8.8 GiB, so I have to build on a 16 GiB card.  My problem is resizing that 8.8 GiB image on first book.  I know I've been unclear.  I apologize.

@bstipe Have a look at pishrink: https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink

If you are trying to minimise image size Bookworm has an annoying tendency to leave behind old modules. Each using ~26MB. You can safely remove with a command. E.g. sudo apt purge linux-image-6.1* will get rid of old 6.1 modules. You strictly only need the latest, but normally the latest 2 are ever used.

I think your question should be "How do I get a Bookworm 32bit or 64bit  image for PI 4 or 3 on a 8G or 16G SD card with root filesystem of 7G". Shrink a preboot image would be xz image. Using Pi imager with edit, on Bookworm 32bit will produce a boot filesystem of 512M and a root filesystem of 4.7G before booting. The `sudo du -h rootfs' = 3.9G.

That makes sense.  After all this I am pretty sure the way the initial resize works currently is that the imager resizes the partition, then there is a resize2fs_once service that does the filesystem on first boot -- meaning if you don't use the imager and just copy it some other way onto a card, resizing won't happen unless you expand the partition yourself.

@goldilocks Remove the file resize2fs_once does not stop resizing.

@bstipe Okay, so the root filesystem (not just the partition it is in) is resized by the imager (I've never used it) before first boot?  I know that's literally what you put in your last comment, but people do get confused by this... It would make sense to have resize2fs_once enabled anyway to simplify things for people who do put the image on the card themself and the expand the partition.  Seems to be a lot of cruft in all this.

To create an device image and populate it from an existing SD card or image:

Calculate the total size of the first partition and the content of the second one, leaving at least an extra 10%. If that is 4 GiB, here's how to create the base image with dd:
dd if=/dev/zero of=new.img bs=4M count=1024


Use fdisk new.img; this will automatically create an MBR table.  You can then create the two partitions:

Copy the offset and size of the first one from your source, probably the start sector is 8192 and the end for a 256 MiB partition is 532480.  Then use t to set the partition type to W95 FAT32 (option c).
Use p to view the current partition table, then create the second one big enough to fill the rest of the image -- beware because the offset of the first one is 8192, fdisk will offer you a default starting offset for the second one before that, you want to use the End of the last one + 1. The default then offered for the end should be fine, and you can leave the default type flag.
Get the PARTUUID used in the source image from cmdline.txt and use x ("expert options") then i to set the one in the new image the same, sans -02.  This is simpler than changing it in cmdline.txt and /etc/fstab.
Use r to get out of expert options then w to write the table and exit fdisk.  You can then double check the img with fdisk -l new.img.


Now mount the two partitions:

Associate a loop device with the image: sudo losetup -P /dev/loop1 new.img

Create the filesystems:
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/loop1p1
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/loop1p2


Create arbitrary mount points, eg., /mnt/img-1 and /mnt/img-2, and mount the partitions there:
sudo mount /dev/loop1p1 /mnt/img-1
sudo mount /dev/loop1p2 /mnt/img-2




You can now copy the data over.  This is much easier if it is not from a running system; if you have no other choice see the caveats here first.
sudo rsync -rtv /source-first-partition /mnt/img-1
sudo rsync -aHAXv /source-second-partition /mnt/img-2



Unmount the partitions (this may take a second, and is important), and you're done. This can then be written directly to an SD card using dd or whatever tool you normally use.
Enabling auto-resizing of the image is a separate issue; raspi-config uses fdisk to grow the partition then resize2fs to grow the filesystem inside (which is pretty much the only way to do this with commonly available tools).  It can be invoked non-interactively this way:
 raspi-config --expand-rootfs

Which could easily be put into a boot service that then disables or deletes itself and reboots (as long as it happens at an appropriate point, or is set as the init= process in cmdline.txt, you'll have to wrap that in another shell script since this command cannot include whitespace -- use the full /usr/bin/raspi-config path as well.
As per Milliway's answer, /usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh is written to be used this way (via init=) -- but contra that answer it isn't used by default anymore (I am very sure it once was, and suspect the Pi imager replaced some of the functionality). Note that it does do a number of other things besides resizing and you should have a look at that before applying it (I would recommend the raspi-config method above instead).

Thank you for taking the time to write this. Using resize2fs seems not to work with the Bookworm version.  I'm able to produce a shrunken image with dd and pishrink.  It's the auto-resize that baffles me.

If you apply resize2fs properly it will work (it resizes the ext4 fs), however, you would have to use fdisk first to enlarge the physical partition. I don't know when that is done on the original image, but those are a) pretty much the only available tools for this (things like gparted are built on top of them), meaning one way or another that's what used by the bookworm vanilla image, and b) bulletproof, there's no nuance of bookworm that could short circuit them.   However, the pi shrink script may make some wrong assumptions that do (I have not looked at it).

Thank you very much for the help.  I have 24 K-12 teachers coming on Saturday and I'm sort-of panicked.  I may need to punt back to a Buster image.

Hmmm -- I did find where fdisk is used in raspi-config, but a lower stress option in this case might be to create/shrink to an ~15 MiB image then use that, and tell them if they want the card filled 100% latter to use raspi-config --expand-rootfs (or you could try thowing that in a service, this executes in non-interactive mode, just noticed it, edited the end above again about that).

Thank you!  That's what I'm going to do, at least for the moment.  I've manually shrunk the 14.3GiB image to exactly 14GiB.  I'm still testing, but I believe I've got an answer for Saturday.  Thank you again!

@BobBrown: Just an offhand comment, and I understand you're under some time pressure, BUT the Image File Utilities may help. One of the modules is named image-shrink; it's probably not a direct solution as it operates on a raw image file, but perhaps you could use elements of the code (it's all bash). And in any case, Image File Utilities is a good resource to know about.

NOTE Raspberry Pi OS already includes a resize script /usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh which is normally run on first boot to expand to full SD size.
This includes code to do a number of other functions (including check/fix PARTUUID).
The resize function can be run from raspi-config
NOTE Bookworm requires a 512MiB boot partition

The normal bookworm image has a 512 MiB boot partition but there's nothing that "requires" this, I think they just decided it might as well be bigger for whatever reason (even though the same base image only uses ~75 MiB of it).  I have bookworm systems with half that and there's no reason to believe it isn't arbitrary.

Also, init_resize.sh is not used anymore by default.  The (3-15-24) stock image instead uses init=usr/lib/raspberrypi-sys-mods/firstboot which is very similar but sans the resizing; then there is /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once, which is initially enabled, but this only calls resize2fs -- there's nothing which actually expands the partition (as init_resize.sh does), imlying to me this is done initially by the rpi imager (which I've never used).   The raspi-config --expand-rootfs function will create and enable an identical resize2fs_once service after applying fdisk.
